# Can I assign a system variable within makefile run from script?

Tags: bash, shell, makefile, gnu-make

I have a bash script which iterates through different sub-projects directories and executes **make** target there.

Each of that makefile can have its own variable e.g. $(MY_FILTERS) assigned withing the makefile. So it is a makefile's internal variable.

Is there a way I can *export* such variable to add it's content to some system/shell variable accessible from the main script?

I hope this is not the case of parent process not being able to be modified by sub process??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I hope this is not the case of parent process not being able to be modified by sub process??*

Hopes dashed, sorry, you have to use some sort of IPC.  This is one way to do it:

```
#!/bin/bash
export pipe="/tmp/mypipe.$$"
trap 'rm "$pipe"' EXIT 
mkfifo "$pipe" 

make &

read myfilters < "$pipe"
echo "myfilters is $myfilters"
```

Makefile:

```
all:
    echo ${MY_FILTERS} > ${pipe}
```

(note that the `echo` is indented with a tab)

Comment: shouldn't it be `echo $(MY_FILTERS) > $(pipe)` ? or maybe `echo $(MY_FILTERS) > ${pipe}`

Comment: Most makes allow either `${ }` or `$( )`.  Macros names of more than one character require braces { } when substituted, single character names do not (although it is still a good idea).  Parentheses ( ) may also be used, but in some versions of make they have special a meaning when handling libraries.